# telegram get time of photo captured

Tags: c#, telegram, telegram-bot

I am writing a small telegram bot in C#. The usage is as follows: A user sends a photo to the bot, the bot takes the photo and inserts it into a folder with the name of the sender and renames the photo to the time the photo was **taken**.

```
Message.Date.ToString("yyMMdd_HHmmss")
```

The problem with this approach is that this returns the `DateTime` the message was sent, not the picture taken.

Furthermore, Telegram removes the metadata from the image itself (as long as it's sent as a picture instead of a file) - so directly accessing the metadata is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you send the image as a file as this causes Telegram to take the unmodified file and sends it to their servers, or you use the caption of the image and write the date when this image has been taken which I guess is not what you want so probably the only way is you send it as a file.

Comment: You are right. I am not happy with it, but there is no other way.